# khan academy: javascript loop taking too long to run

Tags: javascript, algorithm

[image]

I'm reading through the khan academy course on algorithms. I'm at https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/sorting-algorithms/p/challenge-find-minimum-in-subarray

The code challenge is supposed to loop through the array find and return the lowest number in the subarray. I've written code which I think should work, but I'm getting the error in the title. Why?

```
var indexOfMinimum = function(array, startIndex) {
    // Set initial values for minValue and minIndex,
    // based on the leftmost entry in the subarray:  
    var minValue = array[startIndex];
    var minIndex = startIndex;
    var i = minIndex + 1;
    for( i ; array.length ; i+1) {
        if( array[i]< minValue) {
            minIndex = i ;
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    } 

    // Loop over items starting with startIndex, 
    // updating minValue and minIndex as needed:

    return minIndex;
}; 

var array = [18, 6, 66, 44, 9, 22, 14];   
var index = indexOfMinimum(array, 2);
```

Comment: `array.length` (assuming the array isn't empty) will evaluate as true. Meaning your `for` loop will never exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second part of your for loop needs to be something that actually tests for something.  right now it's an infinite loop because its something that's always true

This should fix it:

```
for( i ; i < array.length ; i++) {
if( array[i]< minValue) {
    minIndex = i ;
    minValue = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `i + 1` needs to be `i += 1`

Comment: you are right, sorry I didn't see that at first I edited it to fix it.